# How to customize Carbon diffForHumans in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am newbie of laravel. I wanna use a carbon class. I want to show on my blade like this: 8 days, 12 hours, 33 minutes remanining time.

My source code;

```
$date = Carbon::parse($currentTime);
    $now = Carbon::now('Europe/Istanbul');
    $date->locale('tr');

    if ($date >= $now) {
        $diff = $date->diffForHumans($now);
        return  $diff;
    }
```

What can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use like this;

```php
$diff = $date->diffForHumans($now, ['long' => true, 'parts' => 4]);
```

Diff for humans take a propertiy.

Answer (score 0):

I found out easily this solution on the documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Just type on search "human" and It'll show to you some examples.

Comment: Thanks, actually i looked this docs page, but i dont understand so top of your answer my solution thanks!